# Not able to delete account record using trigger

Tags: trigger

I want to achieve something like this:If an account is created with `Isactive =true`, then record should be deleted automatically.

With this code, after clicking on edit button and saving the record, message is given as account is deleted. But while editing the record, if I make `Isactive=false`, account record is not getting deleted.

trigger:

```
trigger deleteAccount  on Account (after update) {    
    delAccount.deleteAcount(trigger.new);              
}
```

Class:

```
public class delAccount{
    public static void deleteAcount(List<Account> acclist){
        for(Account acc:accList){        
            acclist =[select Id from Account where IsActive__C=:true];   
            delete acclist;                             
        }
}
```

Comment: This question does not make sense. You say you want it to happen when record is created and checkbox = true. They you say when editing, and setting checkbook = false it is not working. Well for starters, you are not inserting you are editing and you set the checkbox to false so I am confused. Also your code shows and update trigger not an insert........Please clarify your question...

Comment: I'm creating a new account record with checkbox=true and saving it. when i am using insert trigger,error message is thrown and record is not saved,hence using update trigger.So,after saving account,i am able to open the record and click on edit button.And then on saving,message is thrown as account is deleted.

Answer (score 4):

First, I'm going to teach you a couple things about triggers based on the code you've provided, then I'll give you my suggestion on how to handle this issue.

In your code, you pass trigger.new to your class. That's a good thing. In your class, you declare trigger.new as `List<Account> acclist` in your method but don't take advantage of that.

In your class method, you do the following:

```
  for(Account acc:accList){        
      acclist =[select Id from Account where IsActive__C=:true];   
      delete acclist;                             
  }
```

First, there's no need to run a query on Account. You're querying ALL Account records when you do this and trying to reassign the values to trigger.new! You can't change the values of trigger.new in an `AfterInsert` trigger.

Sadly, you also don't use the variable `acc` to make this a `for query`. That means the above query would repeat once for each record in `trigger.new`. If you did that, it would actually look more like:

```
acc=[select Id from Account where IsActive__C=:true];
```

That said, I'm confused by the `IsActive__c` field because in your description, you don't use the custom field notation of `__c` and there's an `IsActive field that's not a custom field on Account, so I don't know which field you're actually referring to. I'm going to assume the latter is the correct one and the custom field is a mistake as I continue.

What you can do instead of the above, is sort through the records and add them to a set or list to find the ones where `IsActive=true`. You'd do that like this:

```
list<account>todelete = new list<account>(); 
for(Account acc:accList){ 
   if(acc.IsActive==true){
      todelete.add(acc);
   }
}
delete todelete;
```

That having been said, it would seem to me that the appropriate way to handle this issue would be to use a before insert trigger to do the following:

```
trigger noIsActive on Account (BeforeInsert) {    
    for(account: acc: trigger.new){
        If (acc.isActive == true){
           acc.isActive = false;             
    }
}
```

What the above does, is simply takes all new accounts where `isActive=true` that are being inserted and sets that field to `false`.

I'm assuming you likely have some kind of approval process that each account needs to go through. If that's the case, you can also simply create a validation rule that prevents the record from being saved for a new account if `isActive = true` saving you the trouble of writing a trigger at all.

An account shouldn't be deleted that someone is creating without letting them know and giving them the chance to correct information they may have erroneously entered. Instead, you present them with an error message.

If you're doing this to take care of bulk data insertions, that would be a different matter entirely and something I could understand. However, I'd still want to see a record of what was being deleted so someone could be notified to follow up. One doesn't arbirarily delete records for these kinds of errors without good reason.

Comment: It was not a business requirement and it was a scenario that I simply thought to implement

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
trigger deleteAccount  on Account (after update) {    
if(trigger.isupdate){
    list <Account> acclist=new list<Account>();
    Acclist=[select id,Isactive__c from Account where Id In:trigger.new];
    list <Account> TodeleteAcclist=new list<Account>();
    for(Account acc:Acclist){
       if(acc.Isactive__c==true){
           TodeleteAcclist.add(acc);
       }
    }
    delete TodeleteAcclist;
 }    
}
```

Comment: a code dump without an explanation is not really an answer. please take some time to review [answer] and update your post accordingly. Thanks